# Retrieving call source for a WCF service

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm fighting since two days with a simple question : Is there a way to identify the source of a WCF call ?
I'm trying to find a realiable .Net property that will let the service know the address (URI) of the calling Web Service.
Especially in the case where two Web Services are hosted on the same machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about the calling client do you want to detect??

In .NET 3.5, you can fairly easily find the client's IP address - see [Keyvan's blog post](http://nayyeri.net/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5) on that topic.

Is that what you're looking for?? If not, you'd probably have to add the caller information to the message (or the headers) explicitly for the server to be able to inspect that information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link.
For example I would like to know that the current request on service http://localhost/Provider/Candy.svc is consumed by the service http://localhost/AnotherService/Child.svc.
The goal is to enforce a few access rules in a WCF services Cloud. If everyone could ask every service informations, it would expose confidencial information to anyone, and that I want to avoid in a transparent way. 
And so Is the parameter not really an option as it can be faked quite easily.

Thanks anyway :-)